# mongojs driver not connecting to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongojs

i have been trying to connect to my local mongodb using mongojs package but its not connecting at all. i have my mongo service running on http://127.0.0.1:27017/ and below is my code :

```
    var express = require('express');
var app  = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongo= require('mongojs');
var db=mongo('catalog',['products']);

app.use(bodyParser.json);
//adding our first route  name 
db.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('database connected')
})
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.send('It Worked');
});
app.get('/products',(req,res)=>{
    db.products.find(function (err,docs) {
        if (err) {
            res.json(err)
        }else{
            res.json(docs)
        }
    })
});
```

i have set event on connect to log if the connection is established but nothing is showing up.do you i could use mongoose or some other packages if it doesnt work at all?

Comment: mongo is just a variable besides i changed it just like you said  but it still is not connecting

Comment: Yea my bad. You don't have your database password protected right?

Comment: no its doesnt have any passwords . is there any possiblity that something is blocking the channel for connecting to database on my express server? i mean i can easily type mongo on terminal and it would connect to db and interact but here its making problem

Comment: mongojs dosen't fire the `connect function` until you make the first request to a collection. I tried it. Make a request to your collection and the `on('connect')` will fire. Or in your case go to `/products` in your browser and you can see the `database connected` log in your terminal.

Comment: oh you are right .last day it was connected for 10 minutes then same problem happened . its probably the issue . isnt there any better way requesting instead of browser . sry to ask so much but what was your request on browser , i used http://localhost:27017/catalog or even http://localhost:27017 and got cant be reached .its so strange last day same address would give me some mongo http access error but now its not even loading up the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mongojs` doesn't fire the connect function until you make the first request to a collection. Make a request to your collection and the `on('connect')` function will fire.

Or in your case go to `/products` in your browser and you can see the **database connected** log in your terminal.

If you want to request records from your collection without going to `/products` in your browser then just write your query outside of your `app.get('/products')`.

Make sure you add

```
app.listen(3000, function() { 
  console.log('server is running');
});
```

at the the end and go to `localhost:3000/products` in your browser.